# bytes[0] == 0xFF is always false

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm porting some BLE code from iOS to Android and part of what we need to do is check for some sentinel values. It works fine in iOS but when I put the same code in Android Studio is gives me a warning saying that my conditional is always false.  Here's what I've got:

```
if(bytes[0] == 0xFF && bytes[1] == 0xFF && bytes[2] == 0xFF && bytes[3] == 0xFF && bytes[4])
{
    event.type = EventType.NONE;
}
```

I thought it was something strange with order of operations so I tried wrapping each check it their own parenthesis but it still says the same thing. I'd like to get rid of the warning but I can't seem to manage.

Comment: what's the type of bytes[0]?

Comment: it's a byte, Dalija has the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java byte is signed and can contain values from -128 to 127, `0xFF` is interpreted as integer value and not byte and you are effectively comparing value -1 with 255 therefore your comparison fails.

You should either use `bytes[0] == -1` or  `(bytes[0] == (byte) 0xFF`

Comment: wow, you saved me a lot of trouble